# Three cards are drawn with replacement from a well shuffled pack of cards. Find the probability that the cards drawn are king, queen and jack.

Tags: combinatorics

Three cards are drawn with replacement from a well shuffled pack of cards. Find the probability that the cards drawn are king, queen and jack.

Well, my solution goes like this:

> We consider three events $A$, $B$ and $C$ such $A$: the event for drawing a king, $B$: the event for drawing a queen and $C$:the event for drawing a jack. Now, these three events are independent with respect to each other so, $P(A\cap B\cap C) =P(A)P(B)P(C)$ . So, now $P(A)=\frac{\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{52}{1}}$, $P(B)=\frac{\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{52}{1}}$,$P(C)=\frac{\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{52}{1}}$. So the required probability is $P(A\cap B\cap C)=\frac{\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{52}{1}}\frac{\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{52}{1}}\frac{\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{52}{1}}=\frac{1}{13^3}$

However, the answer in the solution is given as $\frac{6}{2197}$. Where is the solution going wrong? Why is it not valid? I am not quite getting it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer would be correct if the question was asking the probability of three draws with replacement, with the first card being a King, the second card being a Queen and the third card being a Jack - in other words, if the order in which $K, Q$ and $J$ should appear were fixed. But for the given question, they can appear in any order. So you need to multiple your answer by $3!$. Alternatively, you can think of it as follows.

First card can be any of the $12$ cards of ranks $K, Q$ and $J$. Depending on the rank of the first card, the next card has to be one of the $8$ of other two ranks and the last card has to be from the $4$ cards of the last rank.

So the probability is $~ \displaystyle \frac{12}{52} \cdot \frac{8}{52} \cdot \frac{4}{52} = \frac{6}{13^3}$